# How to Run SSIS Package Using Task Scheduler and Batch File

Tags: batch-file, ssis

I have a windows batch file that looks like this:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn\DTExec.exe" /FILE
 C:\SSIS\CARS\CARS\PCarsCallMonthlyCount.dtsx /DECRYPT pswrd /CHECKPOINTING OFF
```

When I run code from the command prompt the SSIS package runs with no errors.  I then created a scheduled task to run and call the same batch file.  The task runs but does not error out or end.

So I then open the batch file from the command prompt and I get this error "Missing argument for option "file". The execute Package Utility application then starts and waits for some input.

So I assume I am missing something in the command and that is why the task does not complete.  How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the command line is exactly how you have it in the batch file, you need to make it all on one line.  It is not getting the second part of /FILE which is your .dtsx file.

Comment: Thank you that solved the problem.  That's what I get for using notepad with word wrap enabled to build the command line.